# After rebasing my feature branch from main, I now have a divergence and then my branch is ahead by X commits

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase, git-remote

I have a feature branch called `feature` I made changes to this local feature branch and I committed them and pushed them. I looked at my branch tree and I noticed my feature branch is not up to date with `main` so now I want to get the changes from `main` and add it to my `feature` branch. Thus, I did `git rebase main` while I was on the `feature` branch but now I get a message stating,

`Your branch and 'origin/feature' have diverged, and have 8 and 3 different commits each, respectively.`

Why? I have no idea so I did what it recommended me to do which is `git pull` but `git pull` is a merge instead of a rebase so I did `git pull --rebase` instead and now I have a message stating,

`Your branch is ahead of 'origin/feature' by 5 commits.`

but why? I don't understand why I have to push these 5 commits or why I have to do a `git pull --rebase`? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`Your branch and 'origin/feature' have diverged` happens if you `git rebase` the branch which was previously pushed to the origin repository. Rebase rewrites history, so after it you'll have different local and remote state.

`git pull --rebase` pulls the commits from the origin/master and applies your changes upon the newly pulled branch history.

To solve this error `Your branch is ahead of…`, run `git push origin`, then you are 5 commits ahead in comparison to `origin`. And there you will not get around a `merge`. But I don‘t know why a `git merge` is not desired.

But in your case, a `git merge main` instead of `git rebase main` in `feature`-branch would have been enough.

Answer (score 0):

> I looked at my branch tree and I noticed my feature branch is not up to date with main […]

You have local commits that are not on your remote yet.

So you probably had something like this (`feature` ahead of `origin/feature`, but does not have all changes of `master`):

```
A-B-C-D           < master, origin/master
   \
    `E-F          < origin/feature
        \
         `-G-H-I  < feature
```

> Thus, I did git rebase main while I was on the feature branch […]

This will get you to (`feature` is now 5 ahead, 2 behind `origin/feature`; ahead/behind really just means "different commits"):

```
    ,E'-F'-G'-H'-I' < feature
   /
A-B-C-D             < master, origin/master
   \
    `-E-F           < origin/feature
```

> […] so I did `git pull --rebase` instead and now I have a message stating,
> `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/feature' by 5 commits.`

`git pull --rebase` is somewhat clever in figuring out what the history should look like and you probably ended up with:

```
A-B-C-D                < master, origin/master
   \
    `E-F               < origin/feature
        \
         `-G''-H''-I'' < feature
```

Because Git `pull --rebase`d your local branch on top of the remote-tracking branch. This gets you "3 commits ahead" (in my example; on your machine it is 5 commits).

The commits don't come out of thin air, they have always been there. You always had local commits that were never pushed. "ahead" (and "behind") only means that you have work that is in sync with the remote repository.

If you check the commits of your branch in the remote repository (e.g. in GitLab's or GitHub's web UI), you will see that there are some commits missing. These commits only exist locally and you can view them with `git log feature` or with a GUI tool such as `gitk`. Those are your "ahead" commits and Git "wants" you to push them, because they only exist locally and have not been synced to the remote repository.

You don't have to push them, but usually you want to :)